# Difference between getting data using Id vs getting data using Name

Tags: javascript, dom

```
     <html>
     <head></head>
     <body onload="DecTime();">
     <label id="decTimer" name="decTimer1">5:00</label>
     </body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
         function(){                 
            console.log(document.getElementById("decTimer").innerHTML);
            console.log(document.getElementsByName("decTimer1").innerHTML);
         }
     </script>
```

output:

1st console : 5:00

2nd Console : undefined

What is the difference? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `getElementById` returns a single element, `getElementsByName` returns a  collection of elements. Elements have a `innerHTML` property, collections don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get**Element**ById and get**Elements**ByName. The second one returns a collection. You should at first get a specific element by index or iterate through the set and then read the `innerHTML`. The returned collection itself doesn't have `innerHTML` property.

Answer (score 1):

IDs are unique, names are not.
Try

```
console.log(document.getElementsByName("decTimer1")[0].innerHTML);
```

Because getElementsByName return a node list, as the name get **Elements** suggests.

Answer (score 0):

JS Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/manishghec/u9q0Lq5t/

The main difference is that get by name comes with object and node list comes at 0th index.

```
 console.log(document.getElementById("decTimer").innerHTML);
 console.log(document.getElementsByName("decTimer1")[0].innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

[**getElementsByName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName)  returns a nodelist collection.So to retrieve value
 using `document.getElementsByName` you need to pass the index

```
function abc(){                 
   document.write('<pre>'+document.getElementById("decTimer").innerHTML+'</pre>');
document.write('<pre>'+document.getElementsByName("decTimer1")[0].innerHTML+'</pre>');
        }  
abc();
```

I can see another issue in your function declaration. A function expression must have a name (in above example `abc`) if it is not an Immediately Invoked function Expression. Otherwise you may see error like `Unexpected token (`

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/spk3wm2e/)